# HTML entities issue on certain special characters

Tags: php, html-entities

In the database, there are some special characters (most likely copied from a Word processor) that are not being properly converted for viewing in HTML.

To diagnose this further, I have just written out the data to a text file.

```
file_put_contents('/tmp/text.txt', $row['text']."\n\n" . htmlentities($row["text"]) . "\n\n", FILE_APPEND);
```

When comparing, I see this:

```
# grep "and knows what" text.txt
and knows what “good” looks like.
and knows what &acirc;��good&acirc;�� looks like.
```

Any idea why the conversion is being thrown off?

This may already be covered somewhere but not exactly easy to search for special characters.

---

## Update

Resolved with htmlentities encoding utf-8. I had tried utf8, but it requires the hyphen.

```
htmlentities($str, $flags, 'utf-8');
```

Comment: Double check that you're using UTF-8 encoding in both the database and the html page you're using that row.

Comment: What charset are you using for the conversion?

Comment: UTF8 is the encoding for the database, but this is just a text file.  Have tried default and utf8 in htmlentities for the encoding.